# Have an airliner's vertical or horizontal stabilizers or rudders ever broken off?

Tags: horizontal-stabilizer, vertical-stabilizer

For a commercial airliner, how strong and reliable are the vertical and horizontal stabilizers and rudders? Can they just break off?

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wclfY0Meruw

Answer (score 2):

They are very strong and reliable. Occurences where they are completely broken off are extremely few and far apart, and in the cases that have happened, usually some kind of abuse took place, such as too harsh control inputs from pilots. In the case of [American Airlines flight 587](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_587), the control system was also a contributing factor.

Lesser damages, such as cracks and deformations are also quite rare, an example of the more serious kind being the [VARA ATR 72 flight](https://www.atsb.gov.au/publications/investigation_reports/2014/aair/ao-2014-032/) during which excessive control inputs damaged the tail assembly.

As anything in airplanes, they are not designed and built to endure everything, as such a design approch would lead to very heavy and/or expensive planes.

Answer (score 1):

On August 12, 1985, a Boeing 747SR operating as [Japan Airlines Flight 123](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Airlines_Flight_123) lost its vertical stabilizer and crashed after the aircrew had struggled for 32 minutes to control the stricken airliner. It is the deadliest single-aircraft accident in aviation history; 498 of 502 aboard were killed.